# good way to parse two different patterns in java

Tags: java

I have data coming as following:

```
key value
<foo.bar> <foo>
<foo bar> foo
<foobar1> foo
```

And I want to parse it...

```
obj.setKey(key);

obj.setValue(value);
```

Now how do i parse this in one function:

So far I have.

```
public void setNTriples(String text){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        int count = 0;
        while(matcher.find()) {
            if (count == 0){
                setKey(matcher.group(1));
                count +=1;
            }
            else if (count == 1){
                setValue(matcher.group(1));
                count +=1;
            }


        }
```

But the above fails for example two and three as those values doesnt have "<" and ">" in it?

How do i solve this??
Thanks

Comment: Will the value ever have spaces in it?

Comment: Change the input format to JSON.

Comment: I'd consider not using a RE. The simplest genuine parser toolkit possible can probably deal with this better. (The productions would be `Line -> Key whitespace Value`, `Key -> Braced Unbraced`, `Key -> Braced Unbraced`, `Braced -> '<' anything-except-right-brace '>'`, `Unbraced -> anything-except-whitespace`. You could probably actually write those in a RE but it'd be kinda ugly.)

Comment: @Fraz Will it ever have spaces in it without brackets?  Show us *invalid* examples, too.

Comment: Actually, I guess a more general advice would be: before writing a nontrivial regexp, jot down a grammar for the syntax of your input. It should be pretty obvious from it if REs can parse it and how to convert the grammar to RE.

Comment: @tieTYT: No.. Sorry.. values cannot have spaces in it.. My bad.. So.. in total there are fundamentally two objects... the first one will be always inside angled brackets.. the second one can be in angled brackets or it can be without breackets.. but no third one (no spaces)

Comment: @tieTYT: ehh what is wrong with me. values cannot have spaces in it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expression should allow you to extract both keys and values (as groups) given that I assume you want to extract both keys and values without the enclosing `<>`:

```
<([^>]*)>\s+[<]?([^>]*)[>]?
```

Here's a TestNG unit test that shows the result:

```
public class RegExTest {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<([^>]*)>\\s+[<]?([^>]*)[>]?");

    @Test(dataProvider = "data")
    public void testRegEx(String line, String k, String v) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if (! m.matches() ) {
            Assert.fail("no match");
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(m.group(1), k);
        Assert.assertEquals(m.group(2), v);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] data() {
        return new Object[][] {
                {"<foo.bar> <foo>", "foo.bar", "foo"},
                {"<foo bar> foo", "foo bar", "foo"},
                {"<foobar1> foo", "foobar1", "foo"}
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you said that "values can't have spaces" in it, you should just be able to do a `String.replaceAll` on the bracket characters to change them into empty strings.  Then `String.split` on whitespace.  Your key is everything but the last piece.  Your value is the last piece.

Answer (score 1):

For your example this one seems to be selecting each word for me: `(<[a-zA-Z.\d\s]+>|\w+)`. I do not know if its the shortest one though.